# How to select a card in a carousel by menu item in a docked menu list in Sencha touch?

Tags: list, sencha-touch, store, carousel

I cannot figure out how I can retrieve a given Data item in a store (id-number) to  send it to the "setActiveItem" method in a listener:
So I have a store - model:

```
    Ext.regModel('PictureItem', {
        fields: ['id', 'titel', 'url']
    });
    var pictureItems = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'PictureItem',
        data: [
            {id:1, titel:'page 1', url:'http://placekitten.com/1024/768'},
            {id:2, titel:'page 2', url:'http://placekitten.com/1024/768'},
            {id:3, titel:'page 3', url:'http://placekitten.com/1024/768'},

        ]
    });
```

Here is my menuList called "leftList":

```
    var leftList = new Ext.List({
        dock: 'left',
        id:'list1',
        width: 135,
        overlay: true,
        itemTpl: '{titel}',
        singleSelect: true,
         defaults: {
            cls: 'pic'
        },
        store: pictureItems,
        listeners:{
            selectionchange: function (model, records) {
                if (records[0]) {
    Ext.getCmp('karte').setActiveItem(!!!Here the number of the selected Item 

or respondend "id" in the data store!!!);               
}                
}
            }

        });
```

and the carousel....

```
       var carousel = new Ext.Carousel({
                id: 'karte',
        defaults: {
            cls: 'card'
                     },


         items: [{
            scroll: 'vertical',
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html: '<img class="orientation" alt="" src="img_winkel/titel_v.jpg">'       
        },
```

If I call

```
Ext.getCmp('karte').setActiveItem(2);
```

it works with the called card - but how can I get the number from the id of the selected item in the menu List /store????
By the way: what does mean:

if (records[0]) {
why [0]?

Comment: `if (records[0])` is because records is always an array, even if it's a single item so checking for records[0] is just to be sure there is at least one item selected.. as for your other question all I'll say is information you want is in records[0].data .. you can't "setActiveTarget" to it because it's not an item in your carousel container..

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE ANSWER FOR MYSELF - IT'S EASY:

```
Ext.getCmp('karte').setActiveItem(records[0].get('id'), {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});
```

The secret to get the record-entry is ".get()":

```
records[0].get('arrayfield')
```

So now I can change the activeItem in the carousel easely...